# YouTrack 5.x OutofMemoryError when running as a webapp of TeamCity 8 install

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0, youtrack

I have YouTrack5.x running as a web app in a Tomcat install of TeamCity 8. How do I set configurations up such that I do not get OutOfMemory errors in the YouTrack logs? YouTrack fails to load pages and the entire Tomcat needs to be restarted.

I tried setting TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS to '-Xmx1200m -XX:MaxPermSize=270m'in teh environment variable, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: In what application do you get this Exception - TeamCity or YouTrack?

Comment: It's YouTrack that has the exception

Answer (score 0):

You should increase Xmx for YouTrack application and restart Tomcat.

Comment: OK, but how do I do that? Is it a parameter to the Teamcity tomcat service in Windows, or something in the webapp config file?  I've already set it in the Envi Variable as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well how did you get current installation - you've installed TeamCity from exe distribution and added youtrack.war after?